# Broadcast event in Angular 6 / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I have the following structure:

```
<app>
  <test-a></test-a>
  <test-b></test-b>
</app>

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
}    

@Component({
    selector: 'test-a',
    templateUrl: './testa.component.html',
})
export class TestAComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: 'test-b',
    templateUrl: './testb.component.html',
})
export class TestBComponent {
}
```

**`Test B` contains selectable items. When one is selected, i'd like to tell Test A that the item was selected...**

I think there are 2 options i'm aware of that can achieve this.

- Use `App` to store the selected item. Modify that selected item in `Test B` and then allow `Test A` to react... but it makes an **ugly tight coupling** between the `Test A` and `Test B` components... and the parent `App` component. I don't like that idea.
- To create some kind of "Event Subscriber" service that stores an array of various Observables which can be subscribed against. My current implementation here (not finished):

// Model required for my own class

```
export class KeyValuePair<T>
{
    public key: string;
    public value: T;

    construct(key: string, value: T) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

// How my implementation might look (wip)

```
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { KeyValuePair } from "../models/keyvaluepair";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventService<T>
{
    protected subscriptions: KeyValuePair<Observable<T>>[];

    public Broadcast(key: string, value: any)
    {
        var observable = new Observable<T>();
        observable.subscribe((a) =>
        {
            return of(value);
        });

        this.subscriptions.push(
            new KeyValuePair<Observable<T>>(
                key, 
                observable
            )
        );
    }

    public Subscribe(key: string): Observable<T>
    {
        var observable = this.subscriptions.find((sub) => {
            return sub.key == key;
        });

        return observable.value;
    }
}
```

// How you might create a event

```
this.testEventService.Broadcast("itemSelected", item);
```

// How it might be used

```
this.testEventService.Subscribe("itemSelected").subscribe((item) => {
    this.changeItem(item);
});
```

However, surely i shouldn't have to write this stuff..? In angularjs and jquery there was a $broadcast and $on kind of thing that made life so simple... what am i missing here? Is there an easier way in angular 6 and typescript?

**Edit:**

I have made a service people can use, please tell me if it sucks: https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1988/oy7ud8L3/

Comment: I think that you can make it easier, I can help if you interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

```
export class EventService<T> {
    protected _eventSubject = new Subject();
    public events = this._eventSubject.asObservable();

    dispathEvent(event) {
       this._eventSubject.next(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: and you can use `eventService.events.subscribe(event => {...})` and `eventsService.dispatchEvent(event)`

Comment: what would event look like in this case?

Comment: Oh, i see, this is just a one use kind of thing? how do i assign a key to it? so i can store different events which have different data?

Comment: whatever you want, in your case you can use something like redux Action - `{ action: 'itemSelected', payload: {} }`

Comment: you also can create difference selectors from this subject 
`public itemSelectedEvents = this.events.pipe(
filter(e => e.action === 'itemSelected'),
map(e => e.payload)
)`

Comment: "so i can store different events which have different data?" - Yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i'll give this a whirl when I get back from work and give you a tick when I get it to work. thanks man!

Comment: Thanks, i read up on Subjects too. perfect choice for the job. Odd there is no premade service for this. had to create the entire thing myself :(

Comment: I've added my final service implementation to the OP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: here my implementation for that service https://jsfiddle.net/izmaylovdev/3ybxwuas/13/

Comment: Oh i see, a subject can have multiple objects in it. Good to know! Thanks. Thank you so much man!